# How to compare string without using strcmp and square brackets?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

So for example I have a struct array with a lot of names in it and I have a pointer point to this struct. And I have a input to let user input the name to match the one in the struct what should I do without using the string and only use pointers?

```
struct people{
   char name[20];
}

people list[10];
people *ptr;
ptr = list;
char lists[20];
char *inpu;
inpu = lists;

cout << "Input name";
cin >> inpu;
```

I tried use this but its not working well.

```
If ( inpu == (*ptr).name){
       cout << "1";
}
else cout << "2";
```

Comment: No, even if they have the same text, they are not the same string and therefore not the same pointer.

Comment: Yea, I tried to cout the input name and the struct name pointer points to and they showed the same but It never cout 1. How could I correct it? Can you help me please

Comment: I want to try another way to solve it with pointer

Comment: @Hong so go on - do it. What's the point of making up restrictions and asking others to get it done?

Comment: @Hong if you just want correct answer you can look up sources of strcmp http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcmp.c

Comment: Convert the character arrays to `std::string` compare using relational operators.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use strcmp, use totallynotstrcmp from [here](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library:string.h:strcmp#Implementation):

```
int totallynotstrcmp(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    while(*s1 && (*s1==*s2))
        s1++,s2++;
    return *(const unsigned char*)s1-*(const unsigned char*)s2;
}
```

Comment: `(unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2` would be shorter and easier to read

Comment: Pedantic: `(*(const unsigned char*)s1 > *(const unsigned char*)s2) - (*(const unsigned char*)s1 < *(const unsigned char*)s2);` which does not overflow.  Copes with the rare `unsigned char, unsigned` having the same range.